# Legacy Eureka Server, Contemporary Spring Boot And Eureka Dependency Mismatch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

We have a legacy Eureka server (seriously old; like 1.3.4 ~2015) marshalling service discovery across a bunch of Scala applications on EC2.

We've built some Spring Boot Java services that use up to date dependencies. We had to change the service discovery URL to the old one (/eureka/v2) in order to register with the Eureka server. Then we ran in trouble using FeignClient (we were getting a 503 trying to access a Rest endpoint). We removed feign and decided to just fetch the service uri via DiscoveryClient. This fails because we find no instances of our target service using:

`discoveryClient.getInstances("our-awesome-service-name")`

. It returns an empty list. However, if we fetch all services and log them using:

`List<String> applications = discoveryClient.getServices();`

we can see all of the services, including the one we're trying to hit with matching service name.

We're sure this is a result of having such an old version of Eureka server running (we can't upgrade it for a month or two) but does anyone know more than us? Is there a workaround or obvious missing interface in version compatibility? We're on spring boot 2.4.5 and so the subsequent version of spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client dependency.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: No workaround that I know of. There were some changes made early on in eureka server to support spring cloud (something around instance id IIRC) that it has depended on ever since. Not sure if that is the issue or not

Comment: It's a useful comment nonetheless. Thank you